# How do I add constraints to dynamodb fields?

Tags: amazon-dynamodb

I have a dynamoDB entry where each item has a `rating` property. I am incrementing the value using an atomic counter using the following expression:

```js
  UpdateExpression: 'set info.rating = info.rating + :val',
```

Is there a way I can limit the maximum rating value without having to read, check the current value against the existing, and then write only if it does not exceed the limit I have set?

Something like the following would be ideal:

```js
  UpdateExpression: 'if (!(info.rating + :val)) set info.rating = info.rating + :val',
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DynamoDB documents don't have fixed schema beyond your partition and sort keys, so there's no way to apply a constraint to a field.

Unfortunately, you also can't perform an 'increment with cap' in a single operation. DynamoDB's update expression support for real-world applications is very poor.

You can take advantage of condition expressions to stop the update if it would exceed the cap:

```
UpdateExpression: 'SET info.rating = info.rating + :val',
ConditionExpression: 'info.rating <= :maxAllowed' // Where :maxAllowed = :cap - :val
```

If this results in a conditional check failure, you know that adding to the existing value would exceed the cap, so you can perform another operation to attempt to set it to the cap:

```
UpdateExpression: 'SET info.rating = :cap',
ConditionExpression: 'info.rating > :maxAllowed'
```

If this fails again, you can loop back and retry the first operation, because something decremented the value between the operations.

**However, if your use case expects the increment to often hit the cap,** you may find it cheaper to just perform a read and write, as it's significantly cheaper than two writes. You should still use a condition expression to ensure that the write doesn't exceed the cap.